# Is it possible to go from the chrome object Inspector in the IDE?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sass, less

[image]

Is it possible to go from code inspection object to the IDE code?
We need that to by clicking on the red block to open the necessary line in the IDE

Comment: What IDE you want to open on click ? I think there is no possibility to achieve something like that in any of them

Comment: Build your own chromium browser and link the click with a plugin (I think you need to make it too ^^) on your IDE.

Comment: Maybe integrated browser inside some IDE. (I don't know about any TBH)

Comment: and if you create a google chrome extension? it somehow possible to get into devtool?